# Django: transfer instance across inline form to template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have related model EntertainmentCollage with image fields and did't now how to transfer instance models to the editing form. I need to display the existing images in the editing form and have the ability to add new ones.

**models.py**

```
class Entertainment(models.Model):
    main_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'where/')
    place = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,  blank=True, null = True) 

class EntertainmentCollage(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'entertainment/portfolio', blank = True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Entertainment, blank = True, null = True)
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_where(request, pk):
    place = Entertainment.objects.get(id=pk)
    FormSet2 = inlineformset_factory(Entertainment, EntertainmentCollage, fields =['img',], extra=6) 
    form = WhereCreateForm(instance=place)
    form2 = FormSet2()

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = WhereCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=place)

            if form.is_valid():      
                form2 = FormSet2(request.POST or None, request.FILES) 
                if form2.is_valid():
                    form.save()  
                    form2.save()                    
            return redirect('entertainment:where_list') 
    else:
        form = WhereCreateForm()
        form2 = FormSet2() 
    return render(request, "entertainment/where_edit.html", {'form': form, 'form2': form2})
```

**html**

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>Editing Where</h2>
                <br>


                <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <p>{{ form.eventname }}</p>
                    <p>{{ form.place }}</p>
                    <p>{{ form.event_date }}</p>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <section class="admin-section">
                {{ form2.management_form }} 
                    <div class="row">
                    {% for frm in form2 %}

                        <div class="col-md-4 admin__block" is-cover="false">
                            <div class="cover__wrapper edit__wrapper">
                                <a class="delete-button">Delete</a>
                                <a class="make-cover-button">Cover</a>
                                <img src="{{ frm.url }}" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="button">Add photo</a>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h4>Description</h4>
                    {{ form.description }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Save">

                    <a href="#" class="button">Cancel</a>
                </section>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

If I try to add

```
collage = EntertainmentCollage.objects.filter(album = place)
```

to my **views.py** and make form2(instance = collage) error occured QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'

**___ UPDATE ___**

I need to get page like http://joxi.ru/Dr8X8w4tkGw1zr

where images are taken from the model EntertainmentCollage, 
and if they are added then I could see them in the form.

Comment: I can't really understand your question. But `filter()` always returns a queryset, perhaps you mean `.get()`.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I updated my question, maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my question was incorrectly asked. I just had to display all the images from the queryset and use the inline form to add a button to add a new image.